# Access global variable from a struct in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to learn SwiftUI, coming from years of experience with C/C++. So apologies for asking the obvious. I just spent close to half an hour trying to do a simple thing with this language (as I was under impression that Swift is an extension of C++.)

Say, I have a struct (or a class):

```
struct GlobalStruct
{
    var str1 : String = ""
}
```

then I declare it on a global scale:

```
var gS = GlobalStruct();
```

and access it from somewhere else:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    gS.str1 = "123"
    
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

But that `gS.str1 = "123"` line gives me:

> Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Why?? What is consecutive there?

Comment: You can't have executing code at the top level of a type, only declarations of properties and functions. Perhaps add an `init()` and move your code there.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Oh, init() acts as a constructor in C++, correct?

Comment: yes, it is a constructor. An excellent source if you are new to Swift is the free on-line book [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html)